# Using XPath with HTML or XML fragment?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I am new to Nokogiri and XPath, and I am trying to access all comments in a HTML or XML fragment.
The XPaths `.//comment()` and `//comment()` work when I am not using the `fragment` function, but they do not find anything with a fragment. With a tag instead of a comment, it works with the first XPath.

By trial and error, I realized that in this case `comment()` finds only top level comments and `.//comment()` and some others find only inner comments. Am I doing something wrong? What am I missing? Can anyone explain what is happening?

What XPath should I use to get all comments in a HTML fragment parsed by Nokogiri?

This example can help to understand the problem:

```
str = "<!-- one --><p><!-- two --></p>"

# this works:
Nokogiri::HTML(str).xpath("//comment()")
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Comment:0x3f8535d71d5c " one ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Comment:0x3f8535d71cf8 " two ">]
Nokogiri::HTML(str).xpath(".//comment()")
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Comment:0x3f8535cc7974 " one ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Comment:0x3f8535cc7884 " two ">]

# with fragment, it does not work:
Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(str).xpath("//comment()")
=> []
Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(str).xpath("comment()")
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Comment:0x3f8535d681a8 " one ">]
Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(str).xpath(".//comment()")
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Comment:0x3f8535d624d8 " two ">]
Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(str).xpath("*//comment()")
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Comment:0x3f8535d5cb8c " two ">]
Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(str).xpath("*/comment()")
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Comment:0x3f8535d4e104 " two ">]

# however it does if it is a tag instead of a comment:
str = "<a desc='one'/> <p><a>two</a><a desc='three'/></p>"
Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(str).xpath(".//a")
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3f8535cb44c8 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3f8535cb4194 name="desc" value="one">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3f8535cb4220 name="a" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3f8535cb3ba4 "two">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3f8535cb3a3c name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3f8535cb3960 name="desc" value="three">]>]
```

PS: Without `fragment` it does what I want, but it also adds some stuff like "DOCTYPE" and I really have only a fragment of a HTML file that I am editing (removing some tags, replacing others).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"descendant::comment()"` and `"descendant::sometag"` works fine in every case, but I still don't understand these differences.

Answer (score 7):

`//comment()` is a short form of `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::comment()`

using this xpath with a fragment ignores the root comments (they are selected by `/descendant-or-self::node()` but they don't have children).

if you use `HTML(str)` you create a document node as the root of all other items. therefore, `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::comment()` does not ignore the top level comments because they are the children of the document node (which itself is selected by `/descendant-or-self::node()`).

I am not sure why `descendant::comment()` works in any case, I would say that it should be `descendant-or-self::comment()`, but never mind.

hope that helps?

Comment: Yes, this helps! Thank you! I don't understand very well what `self` (the context node) would be. `descendant-or-self` is the same of `descendant` but also includes the context node. I've tried with only a comment in the string (`str = '<!-- foobar -->'`) and even in this case it is a descendant and just `descendant::comment()` works.