# Deface and a comment tag?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, deface

trying to get rid of comment tag from HTML.ERB file with use of Deface library.

Any idea what would be the proper selector for the following

`<!-- Get "Open Sans" font from Google -->`
?

Tried to match with

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => 'spree/admin/shared/_head',
                     :name => 'remove-googleapis',
                     :remove => '!--')  # this thows an exception
```

**Update (exception description):**

```
Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError
unexpected '!' after ''
```

Comment: And what happened when you tried to use Deface? You got an exception, but you don't say what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Deface uses Nokogiri, which uses CSS selectors (with jQuery extensions). At the time of writing, there is no way to select a comment node using these selectors. There are several questions on SO looking for ways to select comment tags using jQuery, and most of them point to the [comments plugin](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1563-jQuery-Comments-Plug-in-To-Access-HTML-Comments-For-DOM-Templating.htm). So there is probably no way to do it through the Deface gem.

If you really want to remove the comment nodes, you can look into using the [sanitize gem](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize), or using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) [with xpath selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817843/using-xpath-with-html-or-xml-fragment).

From an engineering POV, it's probably not worth the effort. Why are you trying to remove a harmless comment tag anyway?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've been worried there is no way with Deface library. Though comments are `harmless', leaving them find quite confusing. When I'm updating several blocks of erb code, old comments persists and create an inconsistent mix with my new one. So if anybody opens page's source, finds comments that simply do not match current code. Not to mention redundant amounts of code are to be transferred between peers.

Comment: I updated my answer with another alternative. Please accept my answer if you think it will work for you.

Comment: How can I apply xpath selector to Deface's ? Did tried to pass as a lambda proc ```:remove => ->(s) {Nokogiri::HTML(s).xpath('//comment()')}``` but the comment tag does not get removed.